# Magnifying glass / zoom window to the google map with Drawing Layer

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, vue.js

I want to add a magnifying glass (also called a zoom window) to the google map with Drawing Layer.
By example: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GJjp.png)

I've tried to use Maps Static API, but google.maps.Map events, such as click and mousemove are disabled while drawing on the map and i can't get the coordinates:

```
<img class="magnifying-glass" :src="`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=300x300&zoom=20&maptype=satellite&center=${coordinates.lat},${coordinates.lng}&key=${mapsKey}`">
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Thank you.